# Why my string value store all char arrays from my struct?

Tags: c++, char, fstream, iostream

I reading a file with this data:

```
0001 Howard      Paredes Zegarra     Computacion    
0002 Penny       Vargas Cordero      Industrial     
0003 Sheldon     Cooper Quizpe       Mecatronica
```

my cpp file is this:

```
struct Alumno {
    char    codigo[5];
    char    nombre[12];
    char    apellidos[20];
    char    carrera[15];
};


istream& operator >> (istream &stream, Alumno &record)
{   stream.read(record.codigo, 5);
    stream.read(record.nombre, 12);
    stream.read(record.apellidos, 20);
    stream.read(record.carrera, 15);
    stream.get();
    return (stream);
}



vector<Alumno> load() {
    ifstream file("datos.txt");
    vector<Alumno> students;

    while (!file.eof()) {
        Alumno student = Alumno();
        file >> student;
        students.push_back(student);
    }

    file.close();
    return (students);
}

int main() {
    auto students = load();

    for (auto student : students) {
        string nombre = student.nombre;
        cout << nombre << endl;
    }

    return (0);
}
```

so the problem is when print the variable "nombre" is printing the whole line less the first column. 
The expected output :

```
Howard
Penny
Sheldon
```

But the current output is :

```
Howard      Paredes Zegarra     Computacion    
Penny       Vargas Cordero      Industrial     
Sheldon     Cooper Quizpe       Mecatronica
```

why i am having this output, is this has some problem with pointer char from my struct, any advice would be wonderful. Thanks in advance.
Note: I can not use string for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using C-style string, you need to add a null-terminator after the `char`s you stick in your array. This means you need to increase the size of each `char` array by one. Otherwise when you output, it will keep displaying characters of all the arrays after the array you tell it to print.

Since you are not allowed to use `std::string`, append a null terminator (numeric `0` or character `'\0'`) to the end of your C-style strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot I have to review the topic of C-style strings.